# How to pass variable by reference in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm using Corona SDK.
I want to write a function which receives component as parameter and removes it like that:

```
function removeComponent(component)
    if component then component:removeSelf() end
    component = nil
end
```

Well, it works but my parameter does not get nil after using this function. Probably I have to pass it by reference, but I'm not sure it is possible with Corona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua doesn't support passing by reference, but since it does support return values you can always achieve what you want using this idiomatic approach:

```
function removeComponent(component)
    if component then component:removeSelf() end
    return nil
end
```

And then call it like this:

```
a = removeComponent(a)
```

Edit: It's worth pointing out too that since Lua supports multiple return values and multiple assignments, you never actually need pass-by-reference.  If you need several items updated, pass them in and return them and then do the call as 
    a,b = myFunction(a,b)

Answer (score 4):

This does not really make sense as presented in your example.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Is component a global ? Or a key in a table?

In your example, component is the name of a local variable in your function. Your `component = nil` only removes the value from the local variable, and thus will be lost.

If you want to have global effects, you'd need to pass the *name* of the variable you'd want to eliminate as string:

```
function removeComponent(component)
    if _G[component] then -- exists globally?
         _G[component]:removeSelf()
    end
    _G[component] = nil
end
```

Note that this style of programming (using the global table for this kind of things) is generally not a good idea. In the best case it can surprise you, in the worst case you end up zapping things like standard functions as print.

Therefore I'd recommend puttign things in their own table, and passing it on to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Its not different really than any other language. Passing by a value by reference (in C++ for example) would not stop any program from holding another copy of this same value elsewhere.

I know nothing of Corona, but this isn't really a Corona question so much as a Lua style question. However, if I had wrote it, I would ensure that the 'component' userdata or underlying value would clear itself up. If the userdata was accessed again, it should throw an error complaining about re-using a dead userdata.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code:

```
local component = display.newCircle(100, 100, 100);

local function removeComponent(c)
  if component then component:removeSelf() end
    component = nil
end

removeComponent(component)
if component == nil then print("Component is nil") else print("Component is not nil") end
```

And it prints "Component is nil". Perhaps you have a copy of your component somewere else or may be you forget to call function removeComponent or something else. Need to see more of your code

Comment: you remove a global "component" and not a passed variable "c"